# Datasource in JBoss not picking the right class

Tags: java, jboss, jboss6.x

I am facing a very weird problem using JBoss EAP 6.0

The problem is basically I have configured, a data source in standalone.xml

```
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/jdbc/ejb/testconn" pool-name="test-cluster-Pool" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=testdb;</connection-url>
                <driver>sqlserver-jdbc</driver>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
                    <prefill>true</prefill>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>sa</user-name>
                    <password>sa</password>
                </security>
                <statement>
                    <prepared-statement-cache-size>32</prepared-statement-cache-size>
                    <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>
                </statement>
            </datasource>
```

This is the configuration of the driver, I have installed the same as a module:

```
            <drivers>
                <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
                <driver name="sqlserver-jdbc" module="com.himanshu.jdbc">
                    <datasource-class>com.himanshu.jdbcdriver.datasource.DataSource</datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
```

com.himanshu.jdbcdriver.datasource.DataSource class basically extends com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource:

But when I run a test, I can conclude that its not using the datasource-class that I have mentioned. Because for the two method,

```
@Override
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLServerException {
    System.out.println("TRYING TO GET CONNECTION");
    return null;
}

@Override
public Connection getConnection(String arg0, String arg1)
        throws SQLServerException {
    System.out.println("TRYING TO GET CONNECTION");
    return null;
}
```

And so Ideally the connection should have returned null, but neither the connection is returned as null nor I get these SOP printed, so can't understand where I am actually wrong.

module.xml is something like this:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.himanshu.jdbc">

<resources>
    <resource-root path="custom-datasource-jar-with-dependencies.jar"/>
</resources>
<dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    <module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true"/>
</dependencies>
</module>
```

UPDATE:

It turns out to be a bug in JBOSS:
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBJCA-1014

Answer (score 0):

Jboss instanciate the datasource by is own, the classloader used is not aware of your application classes, that's why you need to provide the driver implementation in jboss module directory when configuring the driver.
 So your class is not visible to jboss and it cannot use it when loading datasource. Unless you add it in a specific jar located in jboss modules directory

See http://magnus-k-karlsson.blogspot.fr/2012/08/how-to-install-mysql-datasource-on.html. to configure a datasource from a module in jboss. care about naming.

Comment: If you look at the configuration here, I am installing it as a module only:

<driver name="sqlserver-jdbc" module="com.himanshu.jdbc">
                    <datasource-class>com.himanshu.jdbcdriver.datasource.DataSource</datasource-class>
                </driver>

I have installed it as a module. I am even able to query from DB, but its using the classes of SQLJDBC4.jar on which I have done extensions.

Comment: did you provide your class packaged in a jar in  $JBOSS_HOME/modules/com/himanshu/jdbc ? same for the original driver impl ? Did you add an explicit dependency on the original driver in your module.xml ? Can you provide this file content ?

Comment: other solution is to modify the original driver jar by adding your class inside, avoid to add 2 modules. It's a bit dirty anyway.

Comment: yep, what I actually did is imported all the classes of sqljdbc4.jar, using maven goals. So in my jar, I am having my custom datasource along with all the classes of SQLJDBC4.jar, and driver class-name is also mentioned in META-INF/service/java.sql.driver in file. 

If you want I can share the sources, let know.

Comment: i don't have the time to setup an environment (currently @ work) just publish the module.xml content in the question

Comment: <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.himanshu.jdbc">

    <!--<properties>
        <property name="jboss.api" value="unsupported"/>
    </properties>-->

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="custom-datasource-jar-with-dependencies.jar"/>
        <!-- Insert resources here -->
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
        <module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>

Comment: better edit your question because code format is not supported in comments. Honestly i don't manage to get the pb, if your jar is well-formed i don't see the failure reason. sry for this useless answser. I'd be gracefull if you can publish the solution when you get it, if you do

Comment: Logged a bug with Jboss lets see what they have to respond.

Comment: Looks like a bug in jboss, better to move to xa-data-source class, if you want to use custom-implementation. NOT HAPPY WITH THIS SOLUTION